# Adding image and text links to the same html div container in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div called "films" and I want to add an image and text that both link to the same webpage. When I do the following, only the text link works and the image link is disabled. When I remove the text link, then the image link works.

```
 var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = myImage.png;
                img.onclick = function() {
                     window.location.href = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/";
                };
                document.getElementById("films").appendChild(img);
                document.getElementById('films').innerHTML += "<br />" + "myText".link("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/") + "<br /><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById('films').innerHTML = `
  <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/">
    <img src='https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BM2MyNjYxNmUtYTAwNi00MTYxLWJmNWYtYzZlODY3ZTk3OTFlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_UY268_CR3,0,182,268_AL_.jpg' />
  </a>
  <br />
  <a href='https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/'>myText</a>
  <br />
  <br />
`
```

```html
<div id="films"></div>
```